# Package missing in current win-64 channels when creating conda everonment for installation GrahpLab create

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, graphlab

For a coursera course I have to install GraphLab Create. I installed Anaconda 
2.0 and Python 2.7. Then I run the following command to create the conda environment from the anaconda 2 command prompt:

`conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0`

Which gives the error message:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Wendy> conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
Using Anaconda Cloud api
site https://api.anaconda.org Fetching package metadata: SSL
verification error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory SSL
verification error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory SSL
verification error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory S.SL
verification error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory SSL
verification error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory S.SL
verification error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory .... Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0*
```

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

`anaconda search -t conda anaconda 4.0|4.0.0*`

However, the search command gives also an error:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Wendy> anaconda search -t conda anaconda 4.0|4.0.0*
'4.0.0*' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda 4.0 is too old. Just install the most current version. This can be done by removing the version number:

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda
```

Comment: I was getting an error "Error:  Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels:
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl". Removing the version number from the command has helped resolve this error.